# How to change activity in Android Studio using a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, kotlin

```
mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)

val navigationView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
    // set item as selected to persist highlight
    menuItem.isChecked = true
    // close drawer when item is tapped
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers()

    // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
    // For example, swap UI fragments here

    true

}
```

I have a navigation drawer in my app, and I can access it and click on the items listed there. However, what is the code I need to add above so that when an item is clicked, it opens up a new activity? I have 10 activities and don't know anything about fragments yet so have to set it so it opens a new activity for now.

Comment: First of all, please do try to google and follow some tutorial before bumping question on SO. Secondly, fragments are changed in navigation drawer instead of activity.

Comment: I did look up loads of tutorials, why are you assuming I didn't?

Is it impossible to change activities using the navigation drawer then?

Comment: Navigation drawer is meant to show different screens using fragment inside single activity. If you want to show some other activity, sure you can. Here you will be replicating nav drawer in every activity, which is not a recommended practice.

Answer (score 0):

`@override 
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
   {int id = item.getItemId();
// then use if and else to know which is selected}`
'